# How to multiply each point with object's transform matrix?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to multiply each point with transform matrix to get updated points but how to do it? 
Below code is on how to calculate transform matrix,

```
<!--fabric js -->
console.log("Matrix :"+polygon.calcTransformMatrix());
```

Comment: Simon Sarris has written a concise [transformation matrix script](https://github.com/simonsarris/Canvas-tutorials/blob/master/transform.js). In particular, his `multiply` and `transformPoint` methods.

Comment: @markE yes I have used the same way to get the updated points (fabric.util.transformPoint(point,matrix)) but when I pass the updated points to draw the polygon , the position gets changed keeping the shape same.

Comment: @markE 1) When i expand the shape and check for transform matrix, it is : [2.677685950413222,0,0,1,327.25206611570246,146.35576211353316]
2) And when i get the updated points using fabric.util.transformPoint(point, matrix) method  with the matrix above and pass the updated points to draw the polygon, the transform matrix i get for newly drawn polygon is : [1,0,0,1,428.04028925619826,176.73076211353316]
3) So the position tx and ty has got significantly changed.
Its changing the position of polygon keeping shape as modified. please help me